# When applying for a Schengen visa, how can I demonstrate that my father is sponsoring the trip?

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, proof-of-funds

I am a 24 old (single) girl from Bangladesh currently residing in UAE with my parents. My university is taking some students to Spain for a week long trip. The university has given me an itinerary that consists of flight details, hotel details, tour details and meals as well (which will be paid for in advance - 49% before visa application and 51% after application). I will go with my university group, be with them during the entire trip and come back with them as well.

However here is a little issue. I left my job a few months ago. I currently have a savings account for which I get statements after every 6 months. As per my visa in UAE, I am currently a student under my father's sponsorship.

What kind of bank documents to I have to submit to prove that my father is paying me the money for the trip?

My account has about AED 15000 (€3,765) as I recently invested most of my savings to work on a business plan for which I don't have a license yet.

Just confused as to what kind of documents in general will they require for successful application.

PS: Our entire family's Schengen visa application got rejected in September last time and the reason was that 'tourism purpose could not be justified'. I believe that was because we didn't submit our company trade license, University enrollment documents and the NOC mentioned only one of the three countries (Austria, Italy and Switzerland) that we were planning to go for.

Comment: Thanks for yiur reply. Where can I verify the minimum requirements?

Answer (score 3):

The [Ministerio de la Presidencia](https://www.boe.es/diario_boe/txt.php?id=BOE-A-2007-9608) by Order PRE/1282/2007 of May 10, 2007 decreed:

> 1. a) Para su sostenimiento, durante su estancia en España, la cantidad a acreditar deberá alcanzar una cantidad que represente en
>      euros el 10% del salario mínimo interprofesional bruto o su
>      equivalente legal en moneda extranjera multiplicada por el número de
>      días que pretendan permanecer en España y por el número de personas
>      que viajen a su cargo. Dicha cantidad será, en todo caso, de un mínimo
>      que represente el 90% del salario mínimo interprofesional bruto
>      vigente en cada momento o su equivalente legal en moneda extranjera
>      por persona, con independencia del tiempo de estancia previsto.
>
>    El tiempo de estancia a tener en cuenta para calcular la cantidad
>      económica exigida será el número de días resultantes desde la fecha de
>      entrada en España hasta la fecha de salida que figure en el billete
>      referido en la letra b) de este apartado, ambas fechas incluidas.

Which roughly translates as:

> The amount to be credited for the duration of the stay in Spain must
>   be 10% of the minimum gross professional salary or its legal
>   equivalent in foreign currency multiplied by the number of days that
>   they intend to remain in Spain and by the number of people travelling
>   in their charge. In any event, this amount will be a minimum of 90% of
>   the gross national minimum wage in force at the time, or its legal
>   equivalent in foreign currency per person, regardless of the expected
>   length of stay.
>
> The time of stay to be taken into account to calculate the required
>   economic amount will be the number of days resulting from the date of
>   entry into Spain until the date of departure that appears in the
>   ticket referred to in letter b) of this section, both dates included.

The latest figure from [Eurostat](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/tgm/table.do?tab=table&init=1&language=en&pcode=tps00155&plugin=1) for Minimum wages EUR/month for Spain (2015) is 756.70, of which 90% is €681 – but this figure will keep changing as labour rates in Spain change.

This is the minimum required for a stay by one person (no accompanying dependants) for up to 10 days. Since your trip is for less than that it applies to you. Were it for longer than 10 days then an extra amount would be required for each extra day.

With a bank statement of your own showing access to 5-1/2 times that you should not require evidence that your father is sponsoring the trip.

An [official version](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/portal/en/serviciosalciudadano/informacionparaextranjeros/paginas/requisitosdeentrada.aspx) has:

> The minimum amount that must be accredited is € 64.53 per person per day, with a minimum of € 580.77 or its legal equivalent in foreign currency.

so is presumably not up-to-date (though it might be de facto the minimum that is accepted).